# How to solve ID1059 Cannot authenticate the user error?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net, web-applications

I am not really experienced regarding a server/IIS issue. So I will try my best to explain the problem.

I have two same web applications on two different servers (Test and Live Server). Both servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5. Both web applications work with HTTPS. The problem is when I use HTTP on both websites, they are showing two different errors:

On the TEST Server, it is showing HTTP 403 Error:
[Error on Test Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAxH.png)

However, on the LIVE Server, it is showing "ID1059 Cannot authenticate the user" Error:
[Error on Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEqtV.png)

I want both servers to show HTTP 403 Error. I have searched on The Internet about the solution. One of the solutions requires me to disable SSL on the web.config

```
<cookieHandler requireSsl="false"/>
```

However, I have checked that both web.config is the same. Both configs have `<cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>`. Therefore, I don't think the config is the issue. Both web applications are also the same.

How do I solve the issue on the LIVE Server? Which additional part should I check?

Comment: The first should be answered by FRT https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis while the second is an unhandled exception in the web app which only the developers know how to debug and fix.

Comment: @LexLi Hi sorry for the late reply. The thing is, they are both the same Web Application, the same version as well. So I thought the issue must be the configuration on the server.